# Session attribute being accessed by another session

Tags: java, jsp, httpsession

On a jsp page, attributes are accessed such as:
List = (List)request.getAttribute("object");

we have multiple users on a server with independent sessions.
Intermittently, we have been noticing that UserA is seeing UserB's request attributes.

EXAMPLE:
UserA has a request attribute "object" set that has 3 elements:
A
B
C

UserB has a request attribute "object" set that has 3 elements:
D
E
F

At some point during their session, when UserA tried to access the attribute "object",
the elements returned are:
D
E
F

which are elements stored in UserB's request attribute.

Any ideas how this could happen?

Comment: I suspect you have Static state some where (may not be related to Session access).

Comment: Looks like you have declared attributes in your servlet or using `static` variables, like a singleton object that holds the connection =\.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
request.getAttribute("object");
```

is returning a request attribute not a Session attribute.
To get a Session attribute you need to use

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("object");
```

Also watch out for using instance variables in your Servlets, they are shared between requests.

Comment: yes, I meant request attribute. we use both, but in this instance it is a request attribute